# Writing Python script for ArcGIS to square polygon corners?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, geoprocessing

I'm looking for a script that will square the corners of polygons that are near 90 degrees but not exactly. Near could be dealt with via a variable, for example within 5 degrees of 90 (85 - 95 degrees).

For a more detailed description and some rather formal pseudo code, please refer to the following ESRI thread ([particularly William Huber's post](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=987&t=106494)).

Comment: Note that the ESRI forums post includes a working spreadsheet, so there is code in addition to pseudocode.  The crux of the matter is solving an optimization problem.  ArcGIS doesn't have tools for this, but its add-ins (such as R and Python) do.  It would be a fun little script to write for those with the skills...(which wouldn't include me: I'm not an ArcGIS programmer).

Comment: The following thread on measuring the angles of the corners of a polygon is a step in the right direction - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/measure-the-angle-of-each-corner-of-a-polygon

Comment: This looks promising! https://github.com/smathermather/pg-orthogonalize

Comment: A similar question on esri forum: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/167086

Comment: @Barbarossa - Here is the ArcGIS tool that the geonet.esri.com makes reference to - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/regularize-building-footprint.htm. I just ran a quick test and the tool works well. Obviously, parameter tweaking is necessary to optimize the results for each use case.

Comment: I think it would be great if you could [edit] your question to revise it in light of your learnings so far.  That way any new potential answerers will be able to just read what you have synthesized as their starting point rather than having to trawl through discussion forum posts to get that.  Please treat my close vote on this as "let's see if we can make some headway" rather than it being a bad question.  It is potentially a great question (as 12 upvotes indicate) but it is asking for script/code with no code included.